# Can anyone define the Windows PE Checksum Algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, checksum, portable-executable

I would like to implement this in C#

I have looked here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/PEChecksum.aspx

And am aware of the ImageHlp.dll MapFileAndCheckSum function.

However, for various reasons, I would like to implement this myself.

The best I have found is here:
http://forum.sysinternals.com/optional-header-checksum-calculation_topic24214.html

But, I don't understand the explanation. Can anyone clarify how the checksum is calculated?

Thanks!

**Update**

I from the code example, I do not understand what this means, and how to translate it into C#

```
sum -= sum < low 16 bits of CheckSum in file // 16-bit borrow 
sum -= low 16 bits of CheckSum in file 
sum -= sum < high 16 bits of CheckSum in file 
sum -= high 16 bits of CheckSum in file
```

**Update #2**

Thanks, came across some Python code that does similar too [here](http://code.google.com/p/pefile/)

```
    def generate_checksum(self):

    # This will make sure that the data representing the PE image
    # is updated with any changes that might have been made by
    # assigning values to header fields as those are not automatically
    # updated upon assignment.
    #
    self.__data__ = self.write()

    # Get the offset to the CheckSum field in the OptionalHeader
    #
    checksum_offset = self.OPTIONAL_HEADER.__file_offset__ + 0x40 # 64

    checksum = 0

    # Verify the data is dword-aligned. Add padding if needed
    #
    remainder = len(self.__data__) % 4
    data = self.__data__ + ( '\0' * ((4-remainder) * ( remainder != 0 )) )

    for i in range( len( data ) / 4 ):

        # Skip the checksum field
        #
        if i == checksum_offset / 4:
            continue

        dword = struct.unpack('I', data[ i*4 : i*4+4 ])[0]
        checksum = (checksum & 0xffffffff) + dword + (checksum>>32)
        if checksum > 2**32:
            checksum = (checksum & 0xffffffff) + (checksum >> 32)

    checksum = (checksum & 0xffff) + (checksum >> 16)
    checksum = (checksum) + (checksum >> 16)
    checksum = checksum & 0xffff

    # The length is the one of the original data, not the padded one
    #
    return checksum + len(self.__data__)
```

However, it's still not working for me - here is my conversion of this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace CheckSumTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\Windows\notepad.exe");

            var PEStart = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0x3c);
            var PECoffStart = PEStart + 4;
            var PEOptionalStart = PECoffStart + 20;
            var PECheckSum = PEOptionalStart + 64;
            var checkSumInFile = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, PECheckSum);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:x}", checkSumInFile));

            long checksum = 0;

            var remainder = data.Length % 4;
            if (remainder > 0)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref data, data.Length + (4 - remainder));
            }

            var top = Math.Pow(2, 32);

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length / 4; i++)
            {
                if (i == PECheckSum / 4)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                var dword = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, i * 4);
                checksum = (checksum & 0xffffffff) + dword + (checksum >> 32);
                if (checksum > top)
                {
                    checksum = (checksum & 0xffffffff) + (checksum >> 32);
                }
            }

            checksum = (checksum & 0xffff) + (checksum >> 16);
            checksum = (checksum) + (checksum >> 16);
            checksum = checksum & 0xffff;

            checksum += (uint)data.Length; 
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:x}", checksum));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm being stupid?

Comment: What about the code do you not understand? Example code would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry - editing to make clearer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, finally got it working ok... my problem was that I was using ints not uints!!!
So, this code works (assuming data is 4-byte aligned, otherwise you'll have to pad it out a little) - and PECheckSum is the position of the CheckSum value within the PE (which is clearly not used when calculating the checksum!!!!)

```
static uint CalcCheckSum(byte[] data, int PECheckSum)
{
    long checksum = 0;
    var top = Math.Pow(2, 32);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.Length / 4; i++)
    {
        if (i == PECheckSum / 4)
        {
            continue;
        }
        var dword = BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, i * 4);
        checksum = (checksum & 0xffffffff) + dword + (checksum >> 32);
        if (checksum > top)
        {
            checksum = (checksum & 0xffffffff) + (checksum >> 32);
        }
    }

    checksum = (checksum & 0xffff) + (checksum >> 16);
    checksum = (checksum) + (checksum >> 16);
    checksum = checksum & 0xffff;

    checksum += (uint)data.Length;
    return (uint)checksum;

}
```

Comment: This isn't correct. It doesn't match the ImageHlp.dll `MapFileAndCheckSum` output. Check out the output using the PE Checksum Executable provided in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19326/An-Analysis-of-the-Windows-PE-Checksum-Algorithm

Answer (score 6):

The code in the forum post is not strictly the same as what was noted during the actual disassembly of the Windows PE code. The [CodeProject article you reference](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/PEChecksum.aspx) gives the "fold 32-bit value into 16 bits" as:

```
mov edx,eax    ; EDX = EAX
shr edx,10h    ; EDX = EDX >> 16    EDX is high order
and eax,0FFFFh ; EAX = EAX & 0xFFFF EAX is low order
add eax,edx    ; EAX = EAX + EDX    High Order Folded into Low Order
mov edx,eax    ; EDX = EAX
shr edx,10h    ; EDX = EDX >> 16    EDX is high order
add eax,edx    ; EAX = EAX + EDX    High Order Folded into Low Order
and eax,0FFFFh ; EAX = EAX & 0xFFFF EAX is low order 16 bits
```

Which you could translate into C# as:

```
// given: uint sum = ...;
uint high = sum >> 16; // take high order from sum
sum &= 0xFFFF;         // clear out high order from sum
sum += high;           // fold high order into low order

high = sum >> 16;      // take the new high order of sum
sum += high;           // fold the new high order into sum
sum &= 0xFFFF;         // mask to 16 bits
```

Comment: Thanks again - have bumped your reply, but marked mine as the answer, as I think it represents the complete algorithm.

Comment: @Mark: certainly, I only intended to illustrate the relevant parts of the article.

Answer (score 2):

Java code below from emmanuel may not work. In my case it hangs and does not complete. I believe this is due to the heavy use of IO in the code: in particular the data.read()'s. This can be swapped with an array as solution. Where the RandomAccessFile fully or incrementally reads the file into a byte array(s).

I attempted this but the calculation was too slow due to the conditional for the checksum offset to skip the checksum header bytes.  I would imagine that the OP's C# solution would have a similar problem.

The below code removes this also.

```
public static long computeChecksum(RandomAccessFile data, int checksumOffset)
                throws IOException {
        
        ...
        byte[] barray = new byte[(int) length];     
        data.readFully(barray);
        
        long i = 0;
        long ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, dword;
        
        while (i < checksumOffset) {
            
            ch1 = ((int) barray[(int) i++]) & 0xff;
            ...
            
            checksum += dword = ch1 | (ch2 << 8) | (ch3 << 16) | (ch4 << 24);

            if (checksum > top) {
                checksum = (checksum & 0xffffffffL) + (checksum >> 32);
            }
        }
        i += 4;
        
        while (i < length) {
            
            ch1 = ((int) barray[(int) i++]) & 0xff;
            ...
    
            checksum += dword = ch1 | (ch2 << 8) | (ch3 << 16) | (ch4 << 24);
            
            if (checksum > top) {
                checksum = (checksum & 0xffffffffL) + (checksum >> 32);
            }
        }
        
        checksum = (checksum & 0xffff) + (checksum >> 16);
        checksum = checksum + (checksum >> 16);
        checksum = checksum & 0xffff;
        checksum += length;
        
        return checksum;
    }
```

I still however think that code was too verbose and clunky so I swapped out the raf with a channel and rewrote the culprit bytes to zero's to eliminate the conditional. This code could still probably do with a cache style buffered read.

```
public static long computeChecksum2(FileChannel ch, int checksumOffset)
            throws IOException {
    
    ch.position(0);
    long sum = 0;
    long top = (long) Math.pow(2, 32);
    long length = ch.size();
    
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[(int) length]);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    
    ch.read(buffer);
    buffer.putInt(checksumOffset, 0x0000);
    
    buffer.position(0);
    while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
        sum += buffer.getInt() & 0xffffffffL;
        if (sum > top) {
            sum = (sum & 0xffffffffL) + (sum >> 32);
        }
    }   
    sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);
    sum = sum + (sum >> 16);
    sum = sum & 0xffff;
    sum += length;
    
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java example is not entirely correct. Following Java implementation corresponds with the result of Microsoft's original implementation from `Imagehlp.MapFileAndCheckSumA`.

It's important that the input bytes are getting masked with `inputByte & 0xff` and the resulting `long` masked again when it's used in the addition term with `currentWord & 0xffffffffL` (consider the L):

```
    long checksum = 0;
    final long max = 4294967296L; // 2^32

    // verify the data is DWORD-aligned and add padding if needed
    final int remainder = data.length % 4;
    final byte[] paddedData = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length
            + (remainder > 0 ? 4 - remainder : 0));

    for (int i = 0; i <= paddedData.length - 4; i += 4)
    {
        // skip the checksum field
        if (i == this.offsetToOriginalCheckSum)
            continue;

        // take DWORD into account for computation
        final long currentWord = (paddedData[i] & 0xff)
                               + ((paddedData[i + 1] & 0xff) << 8)
                               + ((paddedData[i + 2] & 0xff) << 16)
                               + ((paddedData[i + 3] & 0xff) << 24);

        checksum = (checksum & 0xffffffffL) + (currentWord & 0xffffffffL);

        if (checksum > max)
            checksum = (checksum & 0xffffffffL) + (checksum >> 32);
    }

    checksum = (checksum & 0xffff) + (checksum >> 16);
    checksum = checksum + (checksum >> 16);
    checksum = checksum & 0xffff;
    checksum += data.length; // must be original data length
```

In this case, Java is a bit inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

No one really answered the original question of "Can anyone define the Windows PE Checksum Algorithm?" so I'm going to define it as simply as possible.  A lot of the examples given so far are optimizing for unsigned 32-bit integers (aka DWORDs), but if you just want to understand the algorithm itself at its most fundamental, it is simply this:

1. Using an unsigned 16-bit integer (aka a WORD) to store the checksum, add up all of the WORDs of the data except for the 4 bytes of the PE optional header checksum.  If the file is not WORD-aligned, then the last byte is a 0x00.
2. Convert the checksum from a WORD to a DWORD and add the size of the file.

The PE checksum algorithm above is effectively the same as the original MS-DOS checksum algorithm.  The only differences are the location to skip and replacing the XOR 0xFFFF at the end and adding the size of the file instead.

From my [WinPEFile class for PHP](https://github.com/cubiclesoft/php-winpefile/blob/master/support/win_pe_file.php#L1855), the above algorithm looks like:

```
    $x = 0;
    $y = strlen($data);
    $val = 0;
    while ($x < $y)
    {
        // Skip the checksum field location.
        if ($x === $this->pe_opt_header["checksum_pos"])  $x += 4;
        else
        {
            $val += self::GetUInt16($data, $x, $y);

            // In PHP, integers are either signed 32-bit or 64-bit integers.
            if ($val > 0xFFFF)  $val = ($val & 0xFFFF) + 1;
        }
    }

    // Add the file size.
    $val += $y;
```

Answer (score 1):

The CheckSum field is 32 bits long and is calculated as follows

##### 1. Add all dwords (32 bit pieces) of the entire file to a sum

Add all dwords of the entire file **not including the CheckSum field itself**, including all headers and all of the contents, to a dword. If the dword overflows, add the overflowed bit back to the first bit (2^0) of the dword.
If the file is not entirely divisible into dwords (4 bit pieces) see 2.

The best way I know to realize this is by using the GNU C Compilers Integer Overflow Builtin function [__builtin_uadd_overflow](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html).
In the original ChkSum function [documented by Jeffrey Walton](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19326/An-Analysis-of-the-Windows-PE-Checksum-Algorithm) the sum
was calculated by performing an `add (%esi),%eax` where
`esi` contains the base address of the file and `eax` is 0 and adding the rest of the file like this

```
adc 0x4(%esi),%eax
adc 0x8(%esi),%eax
adc 0xc(%esi),%eax
adc 0x10(%esi),%eax
...
adc $0x0,%eax
```

The first `add` adds the first dword ignoring any carry flag. The next dwords
are added by the `adc` instruction which does the same thing as `add` but
adds any carry flag that was set before executing the instruction in addition
to the summand. The last `adc $0x0,%eax` adds only the last carry flag if it
was set and cannot be discarded.

Please keep in mind that the dword of CheckSum field itself should not be added.

##### 2. Add the remainder to the sum if there is one

If the file is not entirely divisible into dwords, add the remainder as a
zero-padded dword. For example: say your file is 15 bytes long and looks like this
`0E 1F BA 0E | 00 B4 09 CD | 21 B8 01 4C | CD 21 54`
You need to add the remainder as `0x005421CD` to the sum. My system is a
little-endian system. I do not know if the checksum would change because of the
this order of the bytes on big-endian systems, or you would just simulate this
behaviour.
I do this by rounding up the `buffer_size` to the next bytecount divisible by 4
without remainder or put differently: the next whole dword count represented
in bytes. Then I allocate with `calloc` because it initializes the memory block
with all zeros.

```
if(buffer_size%4)
  {buffer_size+=4-(buffer_size%4);
...
calloc(buffer_size,1)
```

##### 3. Add the lower word (16 bit piece) and the higher word of the sum together.

`sum=(sum&0xffff)+(sum>>16);`

##### 4. Add the new higher word once again

`sum+=(sum>>16);`

##### 5. Only keep the lower word

`sum&=0xffff;`

##### 6. Add the number of bytes in the file to the sum

`return(sum+size);`

This is how I wrote it. It is not C#, but C. off_t size is the number of bytes in the file. uint32_t *base is a pointer to the file loaded into memory. The block of memory should be padded with zeros at the end to the next bytecount divisible by 4.

```
uint32_t pe_header_checksum(uint32_t *base,off_t size)
  {uint32_t sum=0;
  off_t i;
  for(i=0;i<(size/4);i++)
    {if(i==0x36)
      {continue;}
    sum+=__builtin_uadd_overflow(base[i],sum,&sum);}
  if(size%4)
    {sum+=base[i];}
  sum=(sum&0xffff)+(sum>>16);
  sum+=(sum>>16);
  sum&=0xffff;
  return(sum+size);}
```

If you want you can see the code in action and read a little bit more [here](https://github.com/CoffeeMuffin/uefi-app/blob/main/pe_tools/checksum.md).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve the same issue in Java. Here is Mark's solution translated into Java, using a RandomAccessFile instead of a byte array as input:

```
static long computeChecksum(RandomAccessFile data, long checksumOffset) throws IOException {
    long checksum = 0;
    long top = (long) Math.pow(2, 32);
    long length = data.length();

    for (long i = 0; i < length / 4; i++) {
        if (i == checksumOffset / 4) {
            data.skipBytes(4);
            continue;
        }

        long ch1 = data.read();
        long ch2 = data.read();
        long ch3 = data.read();
        long ch4 = data.read();

        long dword = ch1 + (ch2 << 8) + (ch3 << 16) + (ch4 << 24);

        checksum = (checksum & 0xffffffffL) + dword + (checksum >> 32);

        if (checksum > top) {
            checksum = (checksum & 0xffffffffL) + (checksum >> 32);
        }
    }

    checksum = (checksum & 0xffff) + (checksum >> 16);
    checksum = checksum + (checksum >> 16);
    checksum = checksum & 0xffff;
    checksum += length;

    return checksum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private unsafe static int GetSetPEChecksum(byte[] Array) {
    var Value = 0;
    var Count = Array.Length;
    if(Count >= 64)
        fixed (byte* array = Array) {
            var Index = 0;
            var Coff = *(int*)(array + 60);
            if(Coff >= 64 && Count >= Coff + 92) {
                *(int*)(array + Coff + 88) = 0;
                var Bound = Count >> 1;
                if((Count & 1) != 0) Value = array[Count & ~1];
                var Short = (ushort*)array;
                while(Index < Bound) {
                    Value += Short[Index++];
                    Value = (Value & 0xffff) + (Value >> 16);
                    Value = (Value + (Value >> 16)) & 0xffff;
                }
                *(int*)(array + Coff + 88) = Value += Count;
            }
        }
    return Value;
}
```

If you need short unsafe... (Not need use Double and Long integers and not need Array aligning inside algorithm)